# How to develop a real-time event analytics solution?

Tags: javascript, database, nosql, dom-events, real-time

I need to develop an in-house real-time event analytics solution for our web application (e.g: mixpanel, chartbeat, kissmetrics like tool). We mainly use ruby on rails, Redis, MySql and JavaScript.

The analytics solution must have an API and must be real-time. I've never done any API nor worked with real-time data.

What technologies should I use in order to accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done this kind of project earlier.

1. For the graphs I'd recommend [Google Visualization API](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery.html)
2. For storage I would recommend a Round Robin scheme. There is a Round Robin database engine called [RRDtool](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/), but you can also implement a Task (or table partition) in your MySQL database that would speed queries once the stored data gets too big to be queried fast enough, by deleting (or separating) old data.

Comment: Thank you. Could you also elaborate how you did the tracking API? Did you use Javascript?

Comment: @donald I did a real time logging project, not analytics specifically.  Sorry if I wasn't clear about this. Analytics solutions include real time logging.